# Travis fails first build in matrix

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I have started building my project on travis and, after managing to build with one compiler, I decided to cover more and use matrix builds to build with a variety of compilers on Linux. I have managed to get a configuration that builds successfully for all entries except the first one.  The exact error I get is:

```
$ sudo -E apt-get -yq --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --force-yes install g++-5 libncurses5-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package g++-5
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5'
apt-get.diagnostics
apt-get install failed
```

My travis configuration looks like:

```
sudo: false
language: generic

matrix:
  include:
    - os: linux
      env: COMPILER_NAME=g++ CXX=g++-5 CC=gcc-5
      addons:
        apt:
          source: &sources
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.8
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.7
            - llvm-toolchain-precise-3.6
            - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
          packages:
            - g++-5
            - libncurses5-dev

    - os: linux
      env: COMPILER_NAME=clang++ CXX=clang++-3.8 CC=clang-3.8
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: *sources
          packages:
            - clang-3.8
            - libncurses5-dev

    - os: linux
      env: COMPILER_NAME=clang CXX=clang++-3.7 CC=clang-3.7
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: *sources
          packages:
            - clang-3.7
            - libncurses5-dev

    - os: linux
      env: COMPILER_NAME=clang CXX=clang++-3.6 CC=clang-3.6
      addons:
        apt:
          sources: *sources
          packages:
            - clang-3.6
            - libncurses5-dev

before_script:
  - mkdir -p build
  - cd build

script:
  - cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG .. && make && make runtests
```

At this point I feel like I am missing something obvious. I cannot find any solution to this problem (or simply don't know how to search for it effectively).

I feel I should mention that if I swap the gcc section with one of the clang sections that the clang section will fail and the gcc section will pass.

If I can provide anymore useful information then let me know! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply misspelled sources in the first entry. Corrected that and removed the back referencing and everything is working.